# How to run a program as a service (silent)?

Tags: command-line, python, services

I have a python based server which i start from the terminal. This particular instance of the terminal then gives control to the program, and the program uses it as a kind of logging window, until its closed. Is this normal, or should i somehow try to start the program some other way in which it will simply show as an active process? If i close the terminal from which i started the program, the program dies with it.

Thank you

Comment: PHP is mentioned in this answer but it applies to Python, too:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/26555/running-php-cli-server/26565#26565

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even old bash is using & for sending processes to background, but there is few other ways too .. but basic two are these :

```
1.)$~ your_command > outputfile_for_stdout &
        # runs your command in background, giving you only PID so you can exit that process by `kill -9 PID_of_process`
        # & goes at the end of row      


2.)$~ your_command > outputfile_for_stdout 
        # this will run your program normally
        # press  Ctrl + Z then program will pause
   $~ bg
        # now your program is running in background
   $~ fg
        # now your program came back to foreground
3.)you can run terminal window under screen command so it will live until you either kill it or you reboot your machine
   $~ screen
   $~ run_all_your_commands
       # Ctrl + A + D will then detach this screen
   $~ screen -r will reattach it
```

---

Some other useful commands :

```
   $~ jobs
        # will show you all processes running right now, but without PID
   $~ ps
        # will show you all processes for actual terminal window
```

Comment: Hmmm, i was using command 'top' to view processes till now

Comment: Great solution. Is there way to modify the 1. option so that pid is saved to a file. So a log file and a pid file are generated.

Answer (score 32):

Turn it to a daemon (service)
`daemon --name="yourservicename" --output=log.txt sh yourscript.sh`

Answer (score 7):

```
$ servicename &
```

Using `&` causes the program to run in the background, instead of blocking the shell until the program ends.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Eg. `dixon@dixon-vaio:~$ nautilus &
[1] 11835`. It returns process id and you will new shell prompt. Also check this: [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and).

Comment: I stand corrected. Down vote removed.

Comment: And to ignore all output, you can use `servicename &> /dev/null &`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
start-stop-daemon -SbCv -x your_command
```

here is [init.d script to start and stop a program](http://druss.co/2015/06/run-kestrel-in-the-background/) in the background.

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal you could also run `screen` or follow up you command with `&`. Easy way to run continuous processes.

Comment: just using `&` to background the process in this case is to little, in my opinion. OP states that his server logs to stdout so, with `&` his terminal will be cluttered with output. Also since OP mentions *closing the terminal*, OP will not be able to foreground the process again and all the log-output will be lost. Better, at least, to redirect it to a log file or stick with the `screen` setup - but then please explain the basics of  `screen`to OP (detach/attach/etc)