# Run Node.js as a Service on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, nodejs

I have installed the nodejs server on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. Now I have to start its service automatically. manually starting its services working fine, but the issue is when closing the terminal its app stopped working please advise for the best option.

```
nodejs app.js (working manually)
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install "forever" service provided by npm package.

[forever installation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

Using this you can start/stop your project running in background.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, this looks great! Can I run it for Multiple Apps using a single file.?

Comment: You can use this to run more than one projects simultaneously.

Comment: If it helped you, mark it useful :)

Comment: I appreciate that!!! Thanx

Comment: ou can give up the vote if the question is right May be it help to other users also.

Answer (score 2):

Run:

`$ servicename &`

Using `&` causes the program to run in the background, instead of blocking the shell until the program ends.

OR:

Install daemon:

`sudo apt-get install daemon`

Turn it to a daemon (service)

`daemon --name="yourservicename" --output=log.txt sh yourscript.sh`

You can also use:

`start-stop-daemon -SbCv -x your_command`

Source: [How to run a program as a service (silent)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191709/how-to-run-a-program-as-a-service-silent)

Comment: Does it will work for .sh files only?, Current file is app.js which I have to run in the background for nodejs application.

Comment: Make a script that uses app.js