# Unable to connect to X11 display. is $DISPLAY set? - Yes, it is

Tags: display, scripts, environment-variables

I'm trying to run this in my /etc/init.d/rc.local. I had to manually add the exit 0 because it wasn't there by default if that makes any difference.

```
cd /home/john/xcape && ./xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'
exit 0
```

So to check if it works, I run this, and it returns..

```
$ sudo service rc.local start
Unable to connect to X11 display. Is $DISPLAY set?
```

Yes, it is set.

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
john-Ubuntu:0
```

I went through this tutorial http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/hatshelp/v80/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.hats.doc%2Fdoc%2Fudispenv.htm

I looked around on AskUbuntu and they all seem to point to this same step.

Comment: The commands go in `/etc/rc.local`, `/etc/init.d/rc.local` is the service for running that file. And Upstart controls the environment that it is run in: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2075/whats-the-difference-between-service-and-etc-init-d/47664#47664. Lastly, a GUI command shouldn't go in `rc.local`, it's run too early. Try `~/.profile` or `~/.xsessionrc`, since this is for your user..

Comment: In addition "./xcape" is ambiguous , use the full path in scripts.

Comment: I tried adding the cd /home/john/xcape && ./xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'
exit 0     to the ~/.xsessionrc  and now when I login to the computer, it ignores my password and asks for it again. I can't get into my computer now.

Comment: Thank you, got it to work. I am trying to accept your answer, but it doesn't look like I'm able to, nor can I upvote it because my reputation is too low, but thank you. the problem was the exit 0. Once I got rid of that it started working.