# Mysql didn't startup after rebooting

Tags: server, mysql

After I rebooted my server, everything started up normally except for "mysql", i tried to start it up manually "`/etc/init.d/mysql restart`" or with "`service mysql restart`", it fails

In log file it says:

```
Jul 16 08:13:38 localhost /etc/init.d/mysql[18136]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Jul 16 08:13:38 localhost /etc/init.d/mysql[18136]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

I checked that path, but i didn't find that socket file, please advise?

**Edit:**

```
root@myserver:/var/log# service mysql restart
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                   [ OK ] 
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                   [fail]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to startup mysql in "Safe Mode" to create the sock file and pid file, but it fails for some error "bind",

1. I changed the IP address in "bind ip" parameter in my.cnf to localhost
2. started mysql in safe mode.
3. restarted mysql in normal mode, and everything went fine.

Answer (score 1):

a simple hack:

```
sudo ln -s /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
sudo service mysqld restart
```

---

If this doesn't work then try this:

First find  open socket files for mysql in your system

```
sudo find / -type s 2>/dev/null | grep mysql
```

For my case it's `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

Then edit the configuration file `/etc/my.cnf`

```
sudo gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Then search for `socket` and edit the entry with the output above

```
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: this path doesn't exist `/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock`, there is no socket file under /var/run/mysql/

Comment: what is the result of `sudo ls /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: No such file or directory, as i mentioned, nothing exists under /var/lib/mysql/ directory

Comment: ok wait i'll edit my answer

Comment: after `find / -type s 2>/dev/null | grep mysql`, nothing returned :(

Answer (score 0):

Try `service mysql restart`.
Ubuntu uses upstart for mysql service (see [What's the difference between "Service" and "/etc/init.d/"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2075/whats-the-difference-between-service-and-etc-init-d)), and it's behavior differs from init scripts.

What version of Ubuntu and Mysql are you using?
Could you please post above command output and /var/log/mysql*?

Comment: failed to restart please check output in edit, Mysql version:5.1.37, Ubuntu old: 9.10, mysql logs are empty, it is only logging into daemon.log

Comment: Add to /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

`log            = /var/log/mysql.log` and `log-error       = /var/log/mysql.err`, 
restart and post /var/log/mysql*.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue. And find out that:

1. My Ubuntu MySQL Config file is in `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`
2. That file includes all *.cnf file in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` and `/etc/mysql/conf.d`.
3. the line: `log-error = /var/log/mysql/error.log` is very useful

Open two shell connection. Run this on first server:

- `tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log`

On second server, just restart mysql:

- `service mysql restart`

See the error messages in the error log. In my case, it was these two lines:

- `query_cache_limit    = 1M`
- `query_cache_size     = 16M`

I simply comment them, and somehow the mysql can start again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dear Community bot. Unfortunately, all of my answers came from trial and error. So i don't have any citation.