# Where does Gunicorn come from in `service gunicorn restart`?

Tags: upstart, services

When I `pip freeze`, I do not see  `Gunicorn`. I am wondering where `Gunicorn` comes from when I run `service gunicorn restart/stop`. And what is `service`'s relationship with `Upstart`?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I now understand that in `service gunicorn restart`, `gunicorn` is just the name of a script (sans the `.conf` extension) that I place in `/etc/init/`. `service` is a command that searches for System-V scripts in `/etc/init.d` and Upstart scripts in `/etc/init`.

Can anyone help to see if there are any problems with this table?

```
|------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------|
|                  |          service        |             on a Mac            |
|------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------|
| actual manager   | ?           | init(8)   | launchd                         |
| interface        | ?           | initctl   | launchctl                       |
| name             | System-V    | Upstart   |                                 |
| Script locations | /etc/init.d | /etc/init | ~/Library/LaunchAgents and more |
|------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------|
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "Service" and "/etc/init.d/"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2075/whats-the-difference-between-service-and-etc-init-d)

Answer (score 0):

Now that systemd's the init system in Ubuntu, the table looks more like:

```
+------------------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|                  |                      service                                  |             on a Mac              |
+------------------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| actual manager   | none          | init(8)           | systemd(1)                | launchd                           |
| interface        | /etc/init.d/* | initctl           | systemctl                 | launchctl                         |
| name             | System-V      | Upstart           | systemd                   | launchd                           |
| Script locations | /etc/init.d   | /etc/init         | /etc/systemd              | ~/Library/LaunchAgents and more   |
|                  |               | ~/.config/upstart | /lib/systemd/system, etc. |                                   |
+------------------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```